# I want change backround color on the cell where is no date, but the change have to be by the date

Tags: google-sheets

[image]I tried conditional formatting but that changed only cell with date fill in..Or can I somehow extend value of date on another columns because I need to use it for different data and than change the color of based date of cells...

Gray Bars are passed and I want them auto-changing by the date

Comment: Are you attempting to change the background color of a row or column based on the date in one cell? For example A1 = 12/1/2016 so all fields in the "A" row should appear blue?

Comment: I want to extend value of date on whole row and than I can do it trough conditional formatting

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting can refer to cells other than the current cell. You need to use "custom formula" option of the formatting dialog for this. The formula should be written as it works for the upper left corner of the range that you want to format. Use absolute and relative references according to the logic of formatting. Example:

```
=$A2=Date(2016,12,25)
```

this formats a range such as A2:Z; all columns are affected if the column A has the date 25th of December, 2016.

Another example (which looks like what you want to have in the sheet):

```
=weekday($A2)=1
```

formats the rows where the date in column A falls on a Sunday.